# File API writing file doesn't work Samsung smart tv SDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, samsung-smart-tv

I have this javascript code which makes possible writing in a file

```
{

     var fileSystemObj = new FileSystem();
     var fileObj = fileSystemObj.openCommonFile(curWidget.id + 
                                           ‘/testFile.data’, ‘w’);
     fileObj.writeLine(‘something to write.’);
     fileSystemObj.closeCommonFile(fileObj);

}
```

but it doesn't work. Doesn't even display any error!

Comment: You mean [this FileSystem draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/)? There's hardly any support for that in browsers. What browser does the Samsung TV run? Does it definitely support the FileSystem object?

Comment: @Rup it supported according to the developer guide http://freethetv2011.s3.amazonaws.com/App_Development_Guide_for_Samsung_Smart_TV%5BV1.20%5D%5B1%5D.pdf

Comment: @star try to add `try..catch` statement and alert result

Comment: You need to make sure you create the folder for the curWidget.id value first. The device doesn't create this automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[samsung developer forum (you may not see unless you sign in... )](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=a9484f4bcd9e517b)
I am quoting it.

```
    case tvKey.KEY_RED:
  alert('RED BUTTON!');
  alert('CWID: '+curWidget.id);
  try {
    var fileSystemObj = new FileSystem();
    var fileObj = fileSystemObj.openCommonFile(curWidget.id+'/testFile.data','w');
    fileObj.writeLine('something to write.');
    fileSystemObj.closeCommonFile(fileObj);
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Error: file handling: '+e);
  }
  break;
```

> lead to error:
>   alert() : Error: file handling: TypeError: 'null' is not an object
>   (evaluating 'fileObj.writeLine') 
>   Reading cause same problem.

and solution accepted in that link is:

> I suppose that problem is that you have to create common dir (if does not exist ) at first :

```
var fileObj = fileSystemObj.openCommonFile(filePath, 'w');
if(!fileObj){
var bValid = fileSystemObj.isValidCommonPath(curWidget.id); 
if (!bValid) { 
        fileSystemObj.createCommonDir(curWidget.id);    
}
}
fileObj = fileSystemObj.openCommonFile(filePath, 'w');
fileObj.writeLine('something to write.');
fileSystemObj.closeCommonFile(fileObj);
```

Comment: How to confirm if a device from 2011 is supporting it or not ? where to find documentation about it ? i tested above code it doesn't work on 2011 d series !